# angularjs : directive and ng-class initialization inside ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I have an ng-class initialization issue when I move the code which was in my controller, but related to the DOM, to a directive.
To be short, here is some code:

**view.html**

```
<div ng-repeat="foo in foos" ng-click="rowClick($index)>
    <div ng-class="changeOpacity($index)>
        <span>{{foo.title}}</span>
        <span>{{foo.name}}</span>
        <span>{{foo.date}}</span>
        ...
        // some div with hidden content. Show when clicking on the div
    </div>
<div>
```

**controller.js**

```
$scope.rowClick = function (idx) {
    // unfold the clicked div to show content
};
$scope.changeOpacity = function (idx) {
    if (this is the div clicked) {
        return {dark: true};
    } else {
        return {light: true};
}
```

So when I have a list of div. When I clicked on a div, all the other divs get darker excepts this one.

Everything is working fine when $scope.rowClick and $scope.changeOpacity are in my controller.

When I move rowClick and changeOpcaity to a directive:

**myBar.js**

```
myApp.directive('myBar', function () {
    ...
    return {
        restrict:'A',
        link: function (scope, element) {
           element.bind('click', function () {
               ...
               same code from rowClick
               ...
               scope.changeOpacity = function () {
                   ...
                   same code from changeOpacity
               }
               scope.$apply();
            }
        }),
        changeOpacity: function () {
            ...
            return {light: true} // for all divs
        }
    }
});
```

Now my **view.html** is something like that:

```
<div ng-repeat="foo in foos" ng-click="rowClick($index) my-bar>
    <div ng-class="changeOpacity($index)>
        <span>{{foo.title}}</span>
        <span>{{foo.name}}</span>
        <span>{{foo.date}}</span>
        ...
        // some div with hidden content. Show when clicking on the div
    </div>
<div>
```

But now the divs are not initialized anymore with the ng-class. I have to click one time on each div to initialize it, with the link function which listen to the click.

How can I initialize the ng-class inside the directive ?

Thanx.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you are putting the `changeOpacity` function in your scope only after a click. Do it in the link function instead like this:

```
link: function (scope, element) {
    scope.changeOpacity = function () {
        ...
        same code from changeOpacity
    }
}
```

making it a field of the "directive object" has no effect.

However, in my opinion it would be more elegant to use a model property to indicate if the element is active or not and change this property in an `ng-click` attribute. You can then refer to this property in the `ng-class` directive.

Something like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="foo in foos" ng-click="foo.active = true>
    <div ng-class="{light: active, dark: !active }>
        <span>{{foo.title}}</span>
        <span>{{foo.name}}</span>
        <span>{{foo.date}}</span>
        <div ng-show="foo.active">
            // some div with hidden content. Show when clicking on the div
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Definitely do this one.  It's easy to try and jQuery everything, but in angular, you should really only change your **model**, and let angular change the UI for you.  One improvement to this code I might offer is the ng-click should call a method on the scope and pass `foo` as a param, so that you can darken all other `foos` except the one you clicked.

Answer (score 2):

`ng-repeat` creates a child scope for each item within the array. That means scope within a directive within `ng-repeat` will be the child scope. Thus you can set properties directly on that child scope and use `ng-class`, `ng-show` etc

Following is very basic example of directive to toggle state based on `ng-click` handler

HTML

```
<div ng-repeat="foo in foos" ng-click="rowClick($index)"  my-directive parent-array="foos">
    <div ng-class="{activeClass: foo.isActive}" class="item">
        <span>{{foo.name}}</span>
        <div ng-show="foo.isActive">Hidden content {{$index+1}}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Directive

```
 app.directive('myDirective',function(){
    return function(scope,elem,attrs){
      /* ng-repeat adds properties like `$first` , `$last` that can be helpful*/
      /* set default first element active*/
      if(scope.$first){
        scope.foo.isActive=true;
      }
      var parentArray=scope[attrs.parentArray];
      /* update active state across array*/
      scope.rowClick=function(idx){
        angular.forEach(parentArray,function(item, index){
          item.isActive = idx==index
        })
      }
    }
  })
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/jzQPPiCK0Zo4MRgXVgKs?p=preview)**</kbd>

Here's another approach that stores `currSelected` item in the parent scope ( controller)

```
 app.directive('myDirective',function(){
    return function(scope,elem,attrs){

      /* set default first element active*/
      if(scope.$first){
        scope.foo.isActive=true;
        scope.$parent.currSelected=scope.foo
      }

      /* reset previous activeitem  and make item clicked the active one*/
      scope.rowClick=function(item){
        scope.$parent.currSelected.isActive=false
        scope.$parent.currSelected=item;
        item.isActive=true
      }
    }
  })
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/yj85FIM2n3606rMjaRqo?p=preview)**</kbd>

Comment: Thumbs up for first approach, but I would advise against the second one; accessing $parent is almost always the wrong way to do angular.  The first example you give is both cleaner and more straightforward.

Comment: @Hylianpuffball agree, service is better... was put here mostly to understand scopes. Too much to explain including a service inn this post as well. And I wanted to stay away from islolated scope as well