# Angularjs directive : accessing sibling elements in link function

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I've googled a lot to find an answer to a question which seems fundamental to me, but surprisingly with no success. The official doc left me without answers too.
So the simple question is : how to access sibling elements inside the link function of a directive ?

I have a view with an ng-repeat. My directive bind a click on each of the ng-repeat elements :

```
link: function (scope, element) {
    element.bind('click', function () {
        // how to access element.siblings here ?
...
```

Thanx.

Comment: Have you tried `element.siblings()`? Post complete code of directive

Comment: why don't you use `ng-click`? Please show more code. WHat is objective?

Comment: @Satpal actually the `jQlite` used in `angular.element` doesn't have `siblings` method unless jQuery is loaded

Comment: I wrote this stackoverflow question 2 days ago where there is some code : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20540419/angularjs-directive-and-ng-class-initialization-inside-ng-repeat

Answer (score 5):

If you are working with jQuery you can use the [`.siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/) function. If you only have an [angular.element](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.element), you can access the subsequent siblings with the `.next()` function.

However, since you are using angularjs, I recommend to rely on the model for such kind of interactions instead of accessing DOM elements the "jQuery" way. If you provide more detail on what you are trying to do, somebody might suggest a better way (from a design perspective) to achieve your goal.

Comment: I don't want to include jQuery. The .next() function is not very elegant for my issue. See my comment above where there is a link to my real problem. Thanx.

Comment: Ok, I answered your other question. You should definitely avoid to change classes of sibling elements in this case. There is a reason why angular.element does not support access to siblings.

Comment: Agree on the use of model in the directive (so variables + functions on its $scope). You can use a directive's controller and template just as normal, including Angular bindings, interpolation via {{ }}, and other directives like ngClick, ngIf and ngClass. Unless you have a particular reason, like interacting with an external legacy plugin, these tools can mean you don't need to touch the DOM.

Comment: `next()` only matches next sibling...not all siblings